# How to get the index of a max operation

Tags: python, numpy

I am not sure how to get the index of the following amax function:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).reshape(2, 2, 2)
print(np.amax(a, axis = (1, 2)))
```

np.amax(a, axis = (1, 2)) should be [4, 8], and I am looking for index as [(0,1,1), (1,1,1)], specifically, I want index as [(1, 1) (1, 1)] not considering the layer index.

Comment: Have you looked at `argmax`?

Comment: I am now thinking in the direction of changing `np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a, axis=(1, 2)), a.shape) ` something like this.

Comment: I think I figured out. just make `a` becomes `a[ i ]`, at that layer, you can then perform.

Comment: However, this method needs a for statement, which is not I want, so I am still finding simple ways to use `a[ : ]` instead. But now `a[ : ]` will output the global max, not the local max for each layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [654]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).reshape(2, 2, 2)                              
In [655]: np.amax(a, axis=(1,2))                                                               
Out[655]: array([4, 8])
In [656]: a                                                                                    
Out[656]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

`argmax` does not take the tuple indices.  We can get around that by reshaping:

```
In [662]: np.argmax(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1),1)                                                
Out[662]: array([3, 3])
```

and then reconstruct the full index with:

```
In [669]: idx = np.argmax(a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1),1)                                          
In [670]: idx = np.unravel_index(idx,a.shape[1:])                                              
In [671]: idx                                                                                  
Out[671]: (array([1, 1]), array([1, 1]))
In [672]:                                                                                      
In [672]: idx = (np.arange(a.shape[0]),)+idx                                                   
In [673]: idx                                                                                  
Out[673]: (array([0, 1]), array([1, 1]), array([1, 1]))
In [674]: a[idx]                                                                               
Out[674]: array([4, 8])
```